# No visible @interface for 'GADUNativeCustomTemplateAd' error

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, nsstring

[image]

The error I am getting is:

> no visible @interface for 'GADUNativeCustomTemplateAd' declares the selectors 'performClickOnAssetWithKeycustomClickHandler:clickHandler:'

Can anyone please help me solve this?

### .m file

```
// Copyright 2014 Google Inc. All Rights Reserved.

#import "GADUNativeCustomTemplateAd.h"

@implementation GADUNativeCustomTemplateAd

 - (instancetype)initWithAd:(GADNativeCustomTemplateAd *)nativeCustomTemplateAd {
  self = [super init];
  if (self) {
    _nativeCustomTemplateAd = nativeCustomTemplateAd;
  }
   return self;
}

- (NSString *)templateID {
  return [self.nativeCustomTemplateAd templateID];
}

- (NSString *)stringForKey:(NSString *)key {
  return [self.nativeCustomTemplateAd stringForKey:key];
}

- (UIImage *)imageForKey:(NSString *)key {
  return [self.nativeCustomTemplateAd imageForKey:key].images;
}

- (void)performClickOnAssetWithKey:(NSString *)key withCustomClickAction:(bool)customClickAction {
  dispatch_block_t clickHandler = nil;
  if (customClickAction) {
    clickHandler = ^{
      [self didReceiveClickForAsset:key];
    };
  }
  [self.nativeCustomTemplateAd performClickOnAssetWithKey:key customClickHandler:clickHandler];
}

- (void)didReceiveClickForAsset:(NSString *)key {
  if (self.didReceiveClickCallback) {
    self.didReceiveClickCallback(self.nativeCustomTemplateClient,
                                 [key cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
  }
}

- (void)recordImpression {
  [self.nativeCustomTemplateAd recordImpression];
}

- (NSArray *)availableAssetKeys {
  return [self.nativeCustomTemplateAd availableAssetKeys];
}

@end
```

### .h file

```
// Copyright 2014 Google Inc. All Rights Reserved.

@import Foundation;
@import GoogleMobileAds;

#import "GADUTypes.h"

@interface GADUNativeCustomTemplateAd : NSObject

/// A reference to the Unity native custom template ad client.
@property(nonatomic, assign) GADUTypeNativeCustomTemplateAdClientRef *nativeCustomTemplateClient;

/// A GADNativeCustomTemplateAd which loads native ads.
@property(nonatomic, strong) GADUNativeCustomTemplateAd *nativeCustomTemplateAd;

/// Initializes a GADUNativeCustomTemplateAd.
- (instancetype)initWithAd:(GADNativeCustomTemplateAd *)nativeCustomTemplateAd;

/// The ad clicked callback into Unity.
@property(nonatomic, assign)
GADUNativeCustomTemplateDidReceiveClickCallback didReceiveClickCallback;

/// The custom template ID for the ad.
- (NSString *)templateID;

/// Returns the string corresponding to the specified key.
- (NSString *)stringForKey:(NSString *)key;

/// Returns the native ad image corresponding to the specified key.
- (UIImage *)imageForKey:(NSString *)key;

/// Call when the user clicks on the ad.
- (void)performClickOnAssetWithKey:(NSString *)key withCustomClickAction:(bool)clickAction;

/// Call when the ad is displayed on screen to the user.
- (void)recordImpression;

/// An array of available asset keys.
- (NSArray *)availableAssetKeys;

@end
```

Answer (score 2):

In your *header* file, try changing the `nativeCustomTemplateAd` property declaration from this:

```
@property(nonatomic, strong) GADUNativeCustomTemplateAd *nativeCustomTemplateAd;
```

to this:

```
@property(nonatomic, strong) GADNativeCustomTemplateAd *nativeCustomTemplateAd;
```

...you just might have a silly typo in the *class name*.

Comment: Nice, so I think we solved your original issue :) This *googlesignin error* might be a completely new problem...

Comment: Following SO guidelines, you might be better served opening a *new question* with this other problem (and linking back to this question, as reference).

Comment: so every thing is good but now i got linker command failed to exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: @ompatel If my answer solved your original issue, be sure to accept/upvote it when you get a chance... thanks bro :)

Answer (score 1):

you need define performClickOnAssetWithKey:customClickHandler: int the .h file. and implement this method in this file.

Comment: it is defined as    - (void)performClickOnAssetWithKey:(NSString *)key withCustomClickAction:(bool)clickAction;  in h file

Comment: your answer is very detailed, i just show a method signature. but I find he maybe want to write a recursion method, If I guess right，just fix error line, performClickOnAssetWithKey: withCustomClickAction: but he want cell other, need to define a new method like you say, but no "with" head of "customClickAction:(bool)clickAction; "

Answer (score 0):

You need an @interface/@end section in both your GADUNativeCustomTemplateAd.h file and GADUNativeCustomTemplateAd.m file.

In the m file, it should be right after your #import and before your @implementation, and look like

```
@interface GADUNativeCustomTemplateAd()
// private properties of your GADUNativeCustomTemplateAd class
@end
```

In the h file, it should look like:

```
@interface GADUNativeCustomTemplateAd : UIViewController
{  
}
// public properties of your GADUNativeCustomTemplateAd class
@end
```

If GADUNativeCustomTemplateAd is not derived from UIViewController, you should use whatever class it is derived from.

Comment: ok so i do this but as soon as i put '@interface' it tell me to put '@end' there is nothing in between and the error is still there so can you help me more in detail.

Comment: Show us the contents of your GADUNativeCustomTemplateAd.h file